# MongoDB extract same field from each object in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am performing an aggregation query and I end up with the following Array that contains many objects.

[image]

How can I extract the field `_id` from each one of the afore-mentioned Objects?

Expected output would be an array of each of the `_id`s inside each object

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Expected output would be an array of each of the "_id"s inside each object

Comment: Hi @azal can you share the actual data and query so that we can reproduce it

Comment: Using `$project` and `$map`: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1DaNQpdyy_Y). Is this example correct for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an array of every `_id` into you object you can use a `$map`.

Map is similar as JS map, check this:

```js
const array = [
  {"id": 1,"other": ""},
  {"id": 2,"other": ""},
  {"id": 3,"other": ""},
  {"id": 4,"other": ""},
  {"id": 5,"other": ""}]
console.log(array.map(m => m.id))
```

You can get this approach using [mongo `$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) into a `$project` stage like this:

With this aggregation you are creating a field called `array` where using `$map` return `array.id`, so it creates an array of desired ids.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "array": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array",
          "as": "a",
          "in": "$$a.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1DaNQpdyy_Y)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! I was quite confident about the usage of the map function but did not know how to use it. Cheers

Comment: No problem! Also if the issue has been solved, mark answer as accepted is appreciated.